# Report Server not available after Team Foundation Server 2008 SP1 install

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, tfs

We installed SP1 on our Team Foundation Server 2008 server. Everything seems fine after the install, except there is a red X on the Reports folder in the Team Explorer in Visual Studio. If we attempt to access the Reporting Services web site, we get a message that says that the "report server is unavailable". There were no errors during the installation.

The Reporting Services service started up fine and left no errors in the event log. We looked at the Reporting Services Configuration Tool and everything shows as OK. We tried restarting the RS service and rebooting the machine. Again, no errors but still no report availability.

The SQL Server instance where our data lives is up and running fine and we can query the OLAP cube and the relational side with no problem. All of our developer machines are already at VSTS 2008 SP1. Visual Studio is not installed on the server.

We looked at the logs files in the RS folder and the only errors that show are the ones that we get when we try to access the web site from IE, but that don't seem to contain any more info about the root cause.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'll post any updates on other things we try here.

UPDATE: There is a login error showing up the ReportServer(timestamp).log file. The login on the reporting services service is not the login that is showing up in this error, so I'm not yet sure what process is actually trying to make the connection to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got this resolved. It appears that the TFS 2008 SP1 install process decided to change the identity setting of application pool for the Reporting Services web site. To resolve we needed to:

- Open Internet Information Server Manager
- Go into Application Pools
- Right click on the Reporting Services application pool
- Click on the Identity tab
- Change the account from NetworkService to our TFS domain account
- Edit the rsreportserver.config located in "\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\Reporting
- Change the "NT Authority\NetworkService" to "OurDomain\TFSDomainAccount"
- Restart IIS

Hope this saves someone else some time.

Answer (score 0):

Check the IIS application pools. My feeling is that reporting services doesn't play nice with other web applications (usually I've fixed this in the past by setting a seperate pool for the other applications).

Comment: We'll take a look at that. Thanks. It seems like we would have had a problem before the SP1 install if this was the issue though. We've been running for months with no issues.